# Выводит кракозябры openssl в консоле

Tags: linux, openssl

Выводит кракозябры openssl в консоле.Как исправить?

```
  $ echo 'Текст для шифрования' | openssl enc -a -aes-256-cbc -iter 1000000 -pass pass:12345
    U2FsdGVkX1/z6MRnKC3j4Dj/8jFfVm3J+v/drNVeQ6m3Q5lH4f0sz5k0XpZiMZ4o
    t2GFSUMyh/SHK2lNXYMCBg==

gl@MSI MINGW64 ~
$ echo 'U2FsdGVkX1/z6MRnKC3j4Dj/8jFfVm3J+v/drNVeQ6m3Q5lH4f0sz5k0XpZiMZ4ot2GFSUMyh/SHK2lNXYMCBg==' | openssl enc  -aes-256-cbc -salt -a -d -iter 1000000 -pass pass:12345
╨в╨╡╨║╤Б╤В ╨┤╨╗╤П ╤И╨╕╤Д╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜╨╕╤П
```

Comment: У вас какие-то проблемы с кодировкой в консоли, у меня выводит нормально

Comment: MinGW64 — это Windows у вас? Там наверняка стоит CP866 судя по кракозябрам. Вот и получаете UTF8 как CP866.